store and access custom fields on keycloak
We have set up a keycloak instance runing on K8s, we set up users and clients there using an admin account.
We have set up an internal service (in python) which receives the requests from our services or users, and by contacting keycloak issues the token.
I would like to add further information on keycloak accounts, such as an S3 key/secret , so when a client can have its own S3 credentials secured on keycloak.
I see that there is an option of attributes on users, but not for clients.
What I tried
I noticed that I can export a client and add an attribute there, which is not visible on the UI but still exists on the exported file.
I also notices the Mappers option on the clients menu. I think i could work around it in order to store some extra information the way I need.
My problem
It seems that i can not connect to the keycloak api in order to get the mappers information, If there is an other way to store and fetch my desired data, this will not be a problem.
Questions

Is it a good idea to store our S3 key/secret for each user/client on keycloak
how can I store custom fields on keycloak
How can I get the clients mappers information using python  client or rest calls

Thank you

Further information
In case it makes any difference I am using keycloak V16.1.1
The clients connect using their Id/secret in order to get a token.
